# Search suggestion box inputs space in front of search query

Tags: php, mysql, autosuggest

We have a problem with our search suggestions. Everytime we click on a suggestion at our website, it puts a space in front of the search query, which causes the query to fail.

The code that we use for the suggestions is this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT productnaam FROM product WHERE  merk LIKE      '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
            if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them -  fetching an Object (i like PHP5 btw!).
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    // Format the results, im using <li> for the list, you can change it.
                    // The onClick function fills the textbox with the result.

                    // YOU MUST CHANGE: $result->value to $result->your_colum
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->merk.'&nbsp;'.$result->productnaam.'\');">'
                    .$result->merk.'&nbsp;'.$result->productnaam.''.'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
```

Comment: where does `$queryString` come from? (show the code)

Answer (score 0):

Try out with trim()

```
$queryString = trim($queryString);
```

The trim() function removes whitespaces and other predefined characters from both sides of a string.

Comment: This is where my querystring comes from: (i've added trim, but that doesn't work)

// Is there a posted query string?
  if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
   $queryString = trim($db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']));

Answer (score 0):

try the trim() function as [Sameera Thilakasiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987732/sameera-thilakasiri) specified below and also update your query to something like `"SELECT DISTINCT productnaam FROM product WHERE  merk LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10"` The percent sign on both sides will ensure that your query will select records that contain your input as opposed to records that start with your input.

bellow is some further explanation on the `SQL LIKE` condition that might help you out

```
// This query will look for records that start with "sa"    
select * from table where name like 'sa%' 

// This query will look for records that contain "sa"    
select * from table where name like '%sa%' 

// This query will look for records that end with "sa"    
select * from table where name like '%sa'
```

hope that helps!